# Exception occurred while starting AnthillPro:

Tags: tomcat, anthill

AnthillPro did not load correctly. 
null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.impl.AnthillImpl.if(Unknown Source)
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.impl.AnthillImpl.int(Unknown Source)
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.impl.AnthillImpl.init(Unknown Source)
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.Anthill.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.Anthill.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.urbancode.anthill2.ui.AnthillInitServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
 at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's dying very early in the process. Did you move the installation folder? Is the .anthill2.properties still in tact and in the home directory of the user who the application server is running as?

I'd make sure the user hasn't change as well.

Comment: I had installed the ant hill pro. and also the anthill2.properties is in place.